# turn on 3g mobile data programatically in ios device

Tags: ios, 3g-network

I searched i could not find a proper answer. I want to turn on device's 3g data ON from my ios application. My scenario is initially, I will check whether internet is reachable via wifi/ 3g. If both are not available, I should turn ON device 3g data. I should be able to do it without the help of third party library. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. you can not do it via your application. You can let the user know to go to settings page and turn on the data. But with out user's interaction, it is not possible.

Comment: any possibilities using 3rd party library?

Comment: Nope. Its restricted by Apple.

Comment: @Apurv is there any third party API to on and off data connecction

Comment: @Arpi No, it is not possible. You cant do it.

Comment: but if i want such type of APIs for personal purpose not for iTunes approval then is it possible or not

Answer (score 0):

No the closest you can get is by setting the UIRequiresPersistentWifi boolean in your info plist, which will make iOS present an alert with a button to the settings app, but it also means your app will always show this when opened if you're not connected to wifi (even if you're still on 3G)